# Business Intelligence Center Prerequisites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, licensing, business-intelligence

I have a SharePoint 2013 Farm where the Business Intelligence Center template does not appear in Central Administration when creating a new site collection.

We have Standard license key entered when installing SharePoint 2013. Is a prerequisite for Business Intelligence Center to have the Enterprise product key for SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

Is a prerequisite for Business Intelligence Center to have the Enterprise product key for SharePoint?

**as a short answer**, Business Intelligence Center require SharePoint Enterprise License.

Below is a brief comparison  between **SharePoint Standard** Vs **SharePoint Enterprise** License.

**SharePoint Standard CAL:**

- Sites: a single infrastructure for all your business websites
- Communities: an integrated collaboration platform
- Content: enterprise content management (ECM) for the masses
- Search: people and expertise search, visual previews, visual best bets

**SharePoint Enterprise CAL:**

- Sites: a single infrastructure for all your business websites
- Communities: an integrated collaboration platform
- Content: ECM for the masses
- Search: standard search features plus entity extraction, video search, item recommendations
- Business solutions (includes Access Services and InfoPath Services)
- Business Intelligence for everyone (includes Power View, PerformancePoint Services, Excel Services, and Visio Services)

Check also [the complete comparison between two edition](http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-2013/compare-sharepoint-server-standard-enterprise/)